# Display certain attributes on custom tab in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display certain attributes that have data on a custom tab in woocommerce. I have found several examples of code but none are working for me.

I was given the following code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'remove_product_information', 10, 2 );
function remove_product_information( $product_attributes, $product ) {
        // Remove an attribute from the array
    unset($product_attributes['color']);
    
    return $product_attributes;
}
echo wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
```

but its not filtering anything out it still displays 'color' or any other attribute name I put in there.  Also I need t filter out several attributes, so do I just add additional unset lines? or is there a cleaner way to do that? Any insight on this?

Comment: So the above code does work, I was just using the wrong name for the attribute. I needed to add 'attribute_pa_' so for example 'attribute_pa_brand'

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

If you want to customize single product page attributes, You need to customize/override the product attribute page with your custom attribute page, after that, you can modify the attribute accordingly.

To customise the page like:

```
Copy 
 plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php 
To 
 themes/your-theme/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php
```

and modify that.

**Solution 2:**

You have to define first the desired product attributes slugs in an array, after that you will get in single product pages:

```
add_action( 'display_product_attributes', 'display_product_attributes', 25 );
function display_some_product_attributes(){
// HERE define the desired product attributes to be displayed
$defined_attributes = array('fyllighet', 'carrier', 'billing-e-number');

global $product;
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

if ( ! $attributes ) {
    return;
}

$out = '<ul class="taste-attributes">';

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

    // Get the product attribute slug from the taxonomy
    $attribute_slug = str_replace( 'pa_', '', $attribute->get_name() );

    // skip all non desired product attributes
    if ( ! in_array($attribute_slug, $defined_attributes) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // skip variations
    if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
        continue;
    }

    $name = $attribute->get_name();

    if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {

        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
        // get the taxonomy
        $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
        // get the tax object
        $tax_object = get_taxonomy($tax);
        // get tax label
        if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
            $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
        } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
            $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
            // Trim label prefix since WC 3.0
            if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
               $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
            }                
        }

        $out .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '">';
        $out .= '<p class="attribute-label">' . esc_html( $tax_label ) . ': </p> ';
        $tax_terms = array();

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
            // Insert extra code here if you want to show terms as links.
            array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
        }

        $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '</span><progress value="' . implode(', ', $tax_terms) .
        '" max="10"><div class="progress-bar"><span style="width:'
        . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '0%">'
        . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '</span></div></progress></li>';

    } else {
        $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
        $out .= '<li class="' . sanitize_title($name) . ' ' . sanitize_title( $value_string ) . '">';
        $out .= '<p class="attribute-label">' . $name . ': </p> ';
        $out .= '<progress value="' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '" max="10"></progress></li>';
    }
 }

 $out .= '</ul>';

 echo $out;
 }
```

Comment: yes this was one of the things I previously tried and still did not work for me.

Comment: It's an absolute solution but if it's not working from your end, It means something missing so debug one by one.

Comment: So the code I posted does work, I was just using the wrong name for the attribute. I needed to add 'attribute_pa_' so for example 'attribute_pa_brand'

Answer (score 0):

So the code I posted does work, I was just using the wrong name for the attribute. I needed to add 'attribute_pa_' so for example 'attribute_pa_brand'